# Alpha Transparence in unity particle systems

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want music nodes to get out of my boombox in unity. For that I created 4 notes, which I gave a transparent backround. Now I want these sprites to be used by the particle system in unity. For some reason though unity gives it a backround every time. If I enable Alpha is Transparency, it gets white.

If I use them standalone, they work as they should. Anyone has a clue? [image: The Picture]

[image: The Settings of my png]

[image: Default material used for Paritcle System]

[image: How they look in action with Alpha is transparency on]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the Material `Surface Type` from `Opaque` to `Transparent` or `Transparent Cutout`